# .exe doesn't close properly in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C, I wrote a code to calculate the average of grades, it's fairly simple, but it won't close properly when I run it in the .exe. I'll attach a video showing how it works, first I run it from the code, then from the .exe.

[Video](https://youtu.be/O4wvM_UTKUo)

Comment: Please add your code in text, not just a video.

Comment: If I understand the question, it works as intended.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Videos are worse in basically every way.

Comment: With sound effects? Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the IDE is you're using, it is using a `runner.exe` to wrap the execution of your program and show you that "program stopped, hit any key" sort of prompt.

That doesn't happen for a compiled program, and the console window is closed right away at your `exit(-1)` call.

If you want to see the final output of your program, run it via the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exit(0) instead of exit(-1).